# Stop form submit after page refresh

Tags: jquery

I have simple contact form in my web page. After submitting it, page refreshes. Everything seems to be ok, except if I push browser refresh button I get the browser alert message something like this - "Do you want to submit form again?" Is it possible to prevent browser doing this ? I mean after page refresh stop submitting form again ? Any ideas ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get Has been asked here for million times, some one please find any to close as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

*It's may have many way to solve the problem.*

**Can you shift a disable refreshing page to redirect page?**

***Exp.***

Your `<form>` is in `index.html` and submit to `submitToDB.html` when submiting finishes, you redirected its.

**Or,**

Use Ajax, send by clicking at the button, then disable that button